# Can I safely delete cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56? OpenCart 2.3.0.2

Tags: php

Our `cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56` file is holding a ridiculous amount of data (32g) I have changed it to `/temp` as all of our other sites are set this way without any obvious side effects.

Can we now safely delete the `/sessions/ea-php56` file to recover the data if so how do we go about that?

Also is there a cron to regularly clear the new `/temp` file?

Answer (score 0):

If sessions are hanging around this long you need to investigate why. PHP has a garbage collector that is supposed to remove the sessions as they expire.

32GB of sessions is very high, even for extremely busy sites you should never see more then a few MB unless your PHP application is storing way too much in the sessions.

> Can we now safely delete the /sessions/ea-php56 file to recover the data if so how do we go about that?

Yes, just remove it via SSH. `rm -rf /path/to/directory`. Since the directory clearly contains millions of files I do not suggest using the `*` to glob them, rather remove the entire directory and recreate it if it's still in use. If you do this make sure the re-created directory has the same permissions & ownership as the prior directory.

Removing the session directory will only cause sessions to reset for whoever is using your websites, the data is supposed to be temporary.

> I have changed it to /temp

I assume you mean `/tmp`, and from the information provided it looks like you're using cPanel. Be aware that on cPanel servers `/tmp` is usually a mounted disk image, not a physical partition or `tmpfs` (ramdisk). Access to files in `/tmp` will be far slower due to this and may have quite a large impact on server performance.